# alternative way to use if statement inside a select tag in smarty

Tags: html, if-statement, smarty

I have been using smarty template engine for a while and now I'm facing this situation.

Why is this giving me an error?

```
<select  class="m-wrap span8" name="status" required>
  <option value="" {if $frontuser->status eq ''}selected{/if}>Seleccione</option>
  <option value="1" {if $frontuser->status eq '1'}selected{/if}>No Activo</option>
  <option value="2" {if $frontuser->status eq '2'}selected{/if}>Activo</option>
</select>
```

As you can see I'm calling status attribute from object "frontuser" and what I want to do is to read from the database if status is 1, 2 or empty. So if it's one of those options, the select tag has to show it.

I have tried this before and worked but not with an object, but with an array, as you can see here:

```
<select  class="m-wrap span8 chosen" name="gender" data-with-diselect="1" required>
  <option value=" " {if $okInfo['gender'] eq ' '}selected{/if}>Seleccione</option>
  <option value="1" {if $okInfo['gender'] eq '1'}selected{/if}>Hombre</option>
  <option value="2" {if $okInfo['gender'] eq '2'}selected{/if}>Mujer</option>
</select>
```

Any clues? thanks!

Comment: Try putting status in single quotes? It looks like from the syntax highlighting that you just have a simple problem after the `>` symbol.

Comment: I thought that so, but what can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer, after two days of trying. It was quite simple--- just had to add '' like this:

```
 <option value="2" {if '$frontuser->status' eq ' '}selected{/if}>Seleccione</option>
 <option value="1" {if '$frontuser->status' eq '1'}selected{/if}>No Activo</option>
 <option value="2" {if '$frontuser->status' eq '2'}selected{/if}>Activo</option>
```